# MySql - Is it better to select from many tables with union or using temp tables?

Tags: mysql, union, temp-tables

We have a report that users can run that needs to select records from 5 different services. Right not, I am using UNION to combine all the tables in one query, but sometimes, it was just too much for the server and it crashed!
I optimized bits and pieces of the query (where's and table joins) and there haven't been any crashes since, but the report still takes a long time to load (ie the query is very slow).

The question is, will mysql perform faster and more optimally if I create 5 temp tables for the different service types, and then select from all of the temps? Or is there a different idea?
I could, of course, just use 5 separate selects and then combine them in the code (php). But I imagine this would cause the report to load even slower...

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know a lot about temp tables, but if I did I would probably ask you what kind of data you would like to put into them. I do now that `UNION ALL` is a lot less heavy than `UNION`, so if it makes sense in your situation, you might try that.

Comment: do those selects execute fast separately? may be the reason is something else? maybe your selects need to be optimized.

Comment: Are you sure you need an UNION ? Computing the union of many (large) sets can be very expensive. Perhaps all you need is UNION ALL

Comment: @Spiny I did not know that about UNION ALL, I am currently using UNION. Just read this now www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/10/05/union-vs-union-all-performance/ and I am definitely going to change to UNION ALL, thanks!

Comment: @heximal I optimized the selects, as noted in the question. But my question now is, will using temp tables increase the speed and optimization even more, or is better to remain with union, or rather union all?

Comment: union all will work faster, but idk, if your businnes logic lets use union all. temp tables must not improve performance, because UNION operation creates the same temp tables behind the scene

Comment: @esther Good thing it works, I may even make an answer out of it! Right now I don't feel it's an answer to your question though, as you were asking if unions or temp tables would be better, and I can only begin to answer that when you post the queries (hint, hint) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the limiting factor in speed is the database, not PHP. I'd suggest running seperate queries and let the PHP do the combining, see if that is faster. If you're not storing all data in arrays or doing other heavy processing, I suspect the PHP way is much faster.

(this was actually meant as a comment but don't have those rights yet..)

Comment: but isn't there a speed issue with making five separate trips to the db? I am not familiar with how things work... also, if i do separate queries, how else would i combine them in php without storing the results in arrays??

Comment: For large or complicated tables, a single trip to each of them is faster than joining them all. But this all depends really on how you need to use the data. Are you going to output the data directly to screen? It's hard to tell what the best method if we don't know the table layout or what you're going to do with the data;)